# Bootstrap expand on lg with a set height fails on small screens

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, nav

I have a bootstrap 4 navbar which is set to expand on lg and collapse on small devices. This works on a default navbar height but whenever I set the navbar to a height smaller than the default height the expand for the small devices doesnt work...

**HTML-Code:**

```
<header style="background-color: blue;color: white;font-size: 14px">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-default" style="height:30px">
           <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto flex-row justify-content-start">
             <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="mr-4">
                   <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
             </li>
           </ul>

           <a class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText"
               aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
               <i class="fa fa-road"></i>
           </a>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto d-flex">
                 <li class="nav-item active d-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item active d-inline">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                 </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

The content is also not set in the middle. What am I missing out?
The above shows the following. Even the expand fails

[image]

I want to define the height as 30px and i want the content to center vertically in the set height.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Bootstrap navbar height is not defined by a CSS `height` property, but it changes with `<a>` padding and their content.

Try to add `py-0` CSS class to `<a>` of your navbar to remove padding top and bottom.

See this example: https://codepen.io/navalex/pen/jOPXxor

Answer (score 0):

Setting the height to 30px here is causing your issue:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-default" style="height:30px">
```

Here is a codepen that shows your code in a standard boostrap4 template with that inline style commented out:

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Robulus/pen/xxGPvEL)